# Replace filename using create.PostedFile.FileName C#

Tags: c#

How to replace filename using that code. I tried to search. but could not find it.
File 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\1.heic' is not found.

```
        if (Path.GetExtension(create.PostedFile.FileName).ToLower() == ".heic")
        {
            File.Move(create.PostedFile.FileName, Path.ChangeExtension(create.PostedFile.FileName, ".jpg"));
        }
```

Comment: I assume you have to convert a heic-file instead of just renaming it

Comment: User uploads the `.helic` file and you want to save it as `.png`?

Comment: @fubo I want to rename it, just rename. Do not worry about converting

Comment: @Chetan Yes, I need to rename it. Converting stuff is already impemented

Comment: How about `System.IO.Path.ChangeExtension()`

Comment: This code is unclear. There is no function like rename in C#. You could Move File, Copy File or Change extension of a file.

Comment: you want to rename the file which is already converted and saved? or you want to rename the file which is uploaded via File object? There are many thing unclear in your question.. please provide more details and relevant code.

Comment: @Chetan rename file that been uploaded. create.PostedFile.FileName is actual name of file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Path.GetExtenstion is a function that is returning a string to you.
It doesnt make any changes.
To rename file you could move the file. It could be done using this code:

```
public void RenameFile(string fullNamePath, string newFileName)
{
    var newPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(fullNamePath), newFileName + Path.GetExtension(newFileName));
    System.IO.File.Move(fullNamePath, newFilePath);
}
```

You could call this function like:

```
RenameFile("C:/oldfilename.jpg","newFileName.png");
```

Answer (score 2):

you could use File.Move method:

```
File.Move(myffile, Path.ChangeExtension("C:/oldfilename.jpg", ".jpg"));
```

Comment: `myffile == "C:/oldfilename.jpg"`?

Comment: I used that, but  I need to use not exact file, but create.PostedFile.FileName. and I am getting File 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\1.heic' is not found.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a folder in the web directory to save the files and then save the file.

```
string path = Server.MapPath("~/uploads/");
if (!Directory.Exists(path))
{
     Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
}
            
if (Path.GetExtension(create.PostedFile.FileName).ToLower() == ".heic")
{
   create.PostedFile.SaveAs(path + Path.ChangeExtension(create.PostedFile.FileName, ".jpg"));
}
```

Comment: that's actually does not replace filename

Comment: I edited the answer. And I entered the necessary explanations in it.